# How to iterate over the values of a returned row using the sqlite3 interface for c/c++

Tags: c++, sqlite

I am using the c/c++ interface to sqlite3 to extract data from a table. When using the sqlite3_exec function it, if the response returns something (usually when SELECT is executed), requires a 3rd argument called callback which is composed of a series of character pointer arrays.

```cpp
void retrieve_vertex_from_db()
{
    sqlite3 *db;
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM VERTEX;";
    int exit = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);
    char *messageError;
    exit = sqlite3_exec(db, sql.c_str(), callback, 0, &messageError);
    if (exit != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        cerr << "Error" << messageError << endl;
        sqlite3_free(messageError);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Data selected successfully" << endl;
    }
}
```

My problem arises when separating that information by rows. It seems like all the information were the same column and cannot be separated (see output below) and I don't know how to access each value of a single row.

```cpp
static int callback(void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName)
{
    int i;
    cout << argv[1];
    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        cout << azColName[i] << " = " << argv[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
❯ ./compilado                        
ale
ale
Data selected successfully
```

[Database capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUWXs.png)

Comment: Don't use `sqlite3_exec()` for anything where you need to capture the results; uise a prepared statement and step through it in a loop. See https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html

Comment: Though for just printing out the values, your code looks like it should work properly. What's the value of `argc` in the callback?

Comment: For just printing is fine, but the problem shows up when I try to assign values to variables. argc returns the maximum number of columns the table has (in this case,4). I'll try the link you gave me. Thanks

Comment: So that's not the actual output you're getting with that callback?

Comment: Thanks, I read the link you gave me in the first comment and everything worked!!